# Error when trying to integrate with salesforce mobile push sdk in Android Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilesdk, salesforce-sdk-android, react-native-marketingcloudsdk

Im getting this error when trying to integrate with SF mobile push sdk in Android platform. Any clue how to resolve this?
I have tried changing the gradle/JVM/Kotlin version of the project but no luck.

```
> Could not resolve androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0.
     Required by:
         > com.salesforce.marketingcloud:marketingcloudsdk:8.0.8
      > No matching variant of androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 19, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0.2' but:
          - Variant 'releaseVariantReleaseApiPublication' capability androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0 declares a library, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, with the library elements 'aar' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, packaged as a jar
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 19)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.2')
          - Variant 'releaseVariantReleaseRuntimePublication' capability androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0 declares a library for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
```